# Load the content of many Excel files and populate the column of the department based on the filename

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have the following Excel file :

[image]

I have 5 exact files with the same structure, I managed to use a fooreach loop container to load all the data in the 5 Excel files in the same table (SQL Server)

In the department column, I want to store the ID of the department based on the filename
If data is coming from d001.xls the departmentID will have 1 as a value in all the records.

Comment: There is no question here.  Please post the code you are using and what you tried to do what you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner I already did the loading data but the department column is NULL
In the department column, I want to store the ID of the department based on the filename If data is coming from d001.xls the departmentID will have 1 as a value in all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you used a Foreach Loop Container to load all the files dynamically so in the same container, create a local variable:
[image]

The variable is configured like below :

[image]

and in the Data Flow, add a Derived Column with the following expression :

```
LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::strExcelFile],5),1)
```

[image]

[image]